# how can I improve my component's front-end?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I understand that the question is rather abstract and might get downvoted, but it is very important for me as I am about to start coding LWCs for a client and I am trying to improve my front-end skills. This is a simple LWC that I made to practice:

Container:

```
 <template>
    <lightning-card title="Datatable Container" icon-name="utility:block_visitor">
  <lightning-layout>
    <lightning-layout-item size="5"> 
      <c-data-table></c-data-table>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="7">
      <c-data-table-detail></c-data-table-detail>
    </lightning-layout-item>
  </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

DataTable:

```
<template>
        <div class="slds-m-around_large" style="height: 300px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="id"
                    data={data.data}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide-checkbox-column
                    onrowaction={handleAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>    
        <template if:true={openModal}>
                <!-- shows modal -->
    </template>
```

DataTableDetail:

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-m-around_large">
    <template if:true={recordId}>
      <lightning-record-form
        record-id={recordId}
        object-api-name="Account"
        fields={FIELDS}
        mode="view"
      >
      </lightning-record-form>
    </template>
    <template if:false={recordId}>
      <p>No record selected.!</p>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

I wrapped both DataTable and DataTableDetail in `<div class="slds-m-around_large">` to create a margin between the sides of the card, but it does not seem to work as no change happened. The component looks sort of basic and it feels that there is something missing, but I don't know why. Could you please give me advice or point out my errors?

[image]

Comment: Look through the [Lightning components catalog](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) to consider if there are other containers or visuals (like a card for the detail, for example) you might like to consider using. That you used a layout is an excellent decision since these are responsive.

Comment: BTW, I voted to close this since it is asking an opinionated question.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for your response. Is there any other better place where I can ask this question? :(

Comment: Opinions are way more popular on the Salesforce Developer Forums.

Comment: @PhilW True, but the community is not very active. But anyways, I'll try.

Comment: There are a lot of different communities on there, and it is quite active. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums#!/feedtype=RECENT&dc=Lightning&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS

Comment: There's also [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/), [discord](https://discord.com/invite/8J5mvX7), and [trailblazer groups](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups?tab=featured). In terms of this question - if you can get more specific on what change you'd like to see - this could be an answerable question (without opinion). Essentially, not asking how to "improve" but be specific on what you don't like about the look of it (needs better margin, different colors, etc).

Comment: I'd be happy to try to help hone this question to better suit the SFSE format, but I don't see much that I would consider wrong with this visual save the incorrect padding on the `Display` button.

Comment: Thank you Phil, Chris, David!